# problems with converting to json

Tags: json, erlang

i'm trying to convert it to json via jiffy and get an exception, seem that its correct

```
{"PurchaseOrder",
 [{"PurchaseOrderNumber","99503"},
  {"OrderDate","1999-10-20"},
  {"Address",
   [[{"Type","Shipping"},
     {"Name",[{<<"#text">>,"Ellen Adams"}]},
     {"Street",[{<<"#text">>,"123 Maple Street"}]},
     {"City",[{<<"#text">>,"Mill Valley"}]},
     {"State",[{<<"#text">>,"CA"}]},
     {"Zip",[{<<"#text">>,"10999"}]},
     {"Country",[{<<"#text">>,"USA"}]}],
    [{"Type","Billing"},
     {"Name",[{<<"#text">>,"Tai Yee"}]},
     {"Street",[{<<"#text">>,"8 Oak Avenue"}]},
     {"City",[{<<"#text">>,"Old Town"}]},
     {"State",[{<<"#text">>,"PA"}]},
     {"Zip",[{<<"#text">>,"95819"}]},
     {"Country",[{<<"#text">>,"USA"}]}]]},
  {"DeliveryNotes",
   [{<<"#text">>,"Please leave packages in shed by driveway."}]},
  {"Items",
   [{"Item",
     [[{"PartNumber","872-AA"},
       {"ProductName",[{<<"#text">>,"Lawnmower"}]},
       {"Quantity",[{<<"#text">>,"1"}]},
       {"USPrice",[{<<"#text">>,"148.95"}]},
       {"Comment",[{<<"#text">>,"Confirm this is electric"}]}],
      [{"PartNumber","926-AA"},
       {"ProductName",[{<<"#text">>,"Baby Monitor"}]},
       {"Quantity",[{<<"#text">>,"2"}]},
       {"USPrice",[{<<"#text">>,"39.98"}]},
       {"ShipDate",[{<<"#text">>,"1999-05-21"}]}]]}]}]}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

help please, what's wrong?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your proplists/objects in tuple

instead of `[{a,b}]` should be `{[{a,b}]}`

2. Use binary strings instead of  lists

instead of `"string"` should be `<<"string">>`

3. Rtfm on jiffy data format: https://github.com/davisp/jiffy#data-format

Example:

```
   {[{<<"PurchaseOrder">>,
     {[{<<"PurchaseOrderNumber">>,<<"99503">>},
      {<<"OrderDate">>,<<"1999-10-20">>},
      {<<"Address">>,
       [{[{<<"Type">>,<<"Shipping">>},
         {<<"Name">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"Ellen Adams">>}]}},
         {<<"Street">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"123 Maple Street">>}]}},
         {<<"City">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"Mill Valley">>}]}},
         {<<"State">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"CA">>}]}},
         {<<"Zip">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"10999">>}]}},
         {<<"Country">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"USA">>}]}}]},
        {[{<<"Type">>,<<"Billing">>},
         {<<"Name">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"Tai Yee">>}]}},
         {<<"Street">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"8 Oak Avenue">>}]}},
         {<<"City">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"Old Town">>}]}},
         {<<"State">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"PA">>}]}},
         {<<"Zip">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"95819">>}]}},
         {<<"Country">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"USA">>}]}}]}]},
      {<<"DeliveryNotes">>,
       {[{<<"#text">>,<<"Please leave packages in shed by driveway.">>}]}},
      {<<"Items">>,
       {[{<<"Item">>,
         [{[{<<"PartNumber">>,<<"872-AA">>},
           {<<"ProductName">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"Lawnmower">>}]}},
           {<<"Quantity">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"1">>}]}},
           {<<"USPrice">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"148.95">>}]}},
           {<<"Comment">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"Confirm this is electric">>}]}}]},
          {[{<<"PartNumber">>,<<"926-AA">>},
           {<<"ProductName">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"Baby Monitor">>}]}},
           {<<"Quantity">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"2">>}]}},
           {<<"USPrice">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"39.98">>}]}},
           {<<"ShipDate">>,{[{<<"#text">>,<<"1999-05-21">>}]}}]}]}]}}]}}]}
```

Comment: really problem was that erlsom encode xml to "string"